# Select departments with or without employees. Also select employees if assigned

Tags: sql, database, select

I want to select DNAME, DEPTNO from all departments with or without employees assigned. And if a department does have any employees I want to get their ENAME, EMPNO.

I tried this: select e.empno,e.name,d.deptno,d.dname from emp e  full join dept d
on e.deptno=d.deptno

But it didn't work.

Table structure:

```
DEPT
DEPTNO   DNAME

EMP 
EMPNO ENAME DEPTNO
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OUTER JOIN(LEFT/RIGHT)`

```
SELECT D.DEPTNO,
       D.DNAME,
       E.EMPNO,
       E.ENAME
FROM   DEPT D
       LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP E
                    ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO
```

When the `Department` does not have any employee then `NULL` will be displayed in `E.EMPNO` and `E.ENAME` column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
DEPT.DEPTNO,DEPT.DNAME,EMP.EMPNO,EMP.NAME
FROM
DEPT LEFT OUTER JOIN
EMP ON DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.DEPTNO
```